# Keep getting NullPointerException when trying to write file to internal data

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, writer

I am using the following code to copy a json file from my assets folder to the data folder to use this data at first startup until the real data has loaded:

```
AssetManager am = myContext.getAssets();
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = am.open("settings.json");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        try {
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    myContext.openFileOutput("settings.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            outputStreamWriter.write(line);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Test", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
06-08 14:07:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(10509): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-08 14:07:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(10509):    at     java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:141)
06-08 14:07:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(10509):    at     com.test.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:370)
06-08 14:07:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(10509):    at     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
06-08 14:07:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(10509):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
```

Which is this line:

> outputStreamWriter.write(line);

Comment: what's the content of 370-th line in `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: Sorry I forgot! It's outputStreamWriter.write(line);

Comment: this basically means the constructor for outputstreamwriter returned null. I guess this could happen if the file (settings.json) you have specified is missing. Perhaps put full path of file while trying this out?

Comment: I have this settings.json file inside the assets folder. Or where do you mean exactly? The thing is that I have the same code in another place in my code and there it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a following cycle:

```
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    total.append(line);
}
```

So, obviously, `line` equals to `null` in the end of it. Now, let's take a look at [Writer#write(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write%28java.lang.String%29) implementation. It invokes 3-argument version of the `write()` function which looks like so:

```
public void write(String str, int offset, int count) throws IOException {
    if ((offset | count) < 0 || offset > str.length() - count) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(str, offset, count);
    }
    char[] buf = new char[count];
    str.getChars(offset, offset + count, buf, 0);
    synchronized (lock) {
        write(buf, 0, buf.length);
    }
}
```

If `str` is `null` then `str.length()` will fail with `NullPointerException`.

I think what you need is `outputStreamWriter.write(total.toString());`, not the `outputStreamWriter.write(line);`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! My mistake. With total.toString() it worked!

Answer (score 1):

It's because `line` is null at that point.
Look at the loop:
`while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
   total.append(line);
}`

When the loop is over, `line` is null. 
When you're then trying to run following code:
`outputStreamWriter.write(line);` you are passing null value to the `write` method.

`java.io.Writer.write(String str)` implementation is following:
`write(str, 0, str.length());`
The invocation of length() method on null object cause NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    myContext.openFileOutput("settings.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            outputStreamWriter.write(line);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
```

to

```
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    myContext.openFileOutput("settings.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            outputStreamWriter.write(total.toString());
            outputStreamWriter.close();
```